# Are there Schengen airports besides Budapest with border "holes"?

Tags: schengen, borders, covid-19, event-based-effects, bud

Due to COVID-19, many Schengen arrivals in Budapest take place at the non-Schengen sector. As such, despite doing a Schengen -> non-Schengen transfer, I won't be clearing any Schengen exit control at all. Beats me how those needing an exit stamp would get one (I just e-mailed the airport police and asked out of curiosity - the officers hanging around here don't speak English).

Are there any other Schengen airports with this, IMO, serious hole in the external Schengen border?

Comment: Wouldn't this question be very much short-lived?

Comment: Not an airport, but I left Schengen without exit controls or an exit stamp by [walking into Gibraltar once](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/72228/how-does-schengen-know-i-didnt-overstay-if-exiting-through-gibraltar-by-air) (I did subsequently walk across an airport, and could have boarded a flight there presumably). The answer to that question points out a few other such holes.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.