# Overstayed Schengen by many months, best place to leave EU from to go back to the US to apply for a proper visa?

Tags: schengen-visas, us-citizens, overstaying, visa-bans, fines

I have an American friend who was a graduate student in Berlin and entered Germany 4/1/22. She has taken a break from studies and has been traveling around Europe since, thinking that each new country allowed her 90 days there.

She is now in Sicily and wants to return to the US to apply for a learning visa to study Italian for a year in Sicily.

She has been told that it depends on the agent as to whether she will get fined or barred from returning.

Any suggestions on the best place to leave the Schengen Area where she might not get barred and would get the least fine?

Comment: Exactly how long is her overstay? How has she been financing her travels around Europe? AFAIK the penalty for overstaying depends on national law, not the whim of a Border Agent. In Italy, the fine might be between €5,000 and €10,000. In Germany, a fine of up to €3,000 is possible while in Spain it can range from €500 to €10,000. I’ve seen anecdotal reports of France fining overstayers €100 per day of overstay. She  is also likely to be banned banned from returning to the Schengen area for some length of time.

Comment: @Traveller if she arrived on April 22nd of this year then that means an overstay of about 4 and a half months… If that overstay is entered into the system I don’t see her getting a visa or being allowed back into Schengen anytime soon. There are probably ways to avoid that but I don’t think it’s appropriate to discuss those here.

Comment: More than a year, due to the fact she thought going to different countries extended the 90 days. She has savings that she is living on and can support herself without having to work. The biggest is issue is being banned from returning. A lawyer in Italy has told her that it depends on the border agent. She is wondering where she has the best chance of not being barred from returning?

Comment: If 4/1/22 means April 1, 2022, then she has been overstaying for a very long time indeed, about a year and a half. Forget about coming back. That option is most probably gone. The main/only issue is the fine. Indeed shopping for an exit point will make a financial difference, but once the overstay is in the system, no Schengen country will ever issue her a visa...

Comment: 'a graduate student in Berlin' without a visa/residence permit in Germany?

Comment: Please don't use ambiguous date formats. Is that 4 January or April 1?

Comment: Since you don’t get a new stamp by going to a different Schengen country, I really wonder how she got the idea this would work…

Comment: @dda and jcaron What do you mean by “entered into the system”. AFAIK, there is still no Schengen-wide system to record an overstay (or a stay of any kind), what can be shared are bans (technically: an alert for the purpose of refusing entry in the SIS), hence the question: Would all countries actually issue a ban in this situation? The fine is actually the less important part.

Comment: Obviously, depending on the visa application procedure for the study visa visa, there are still ways this long overstay could be an issue even without a ban: You cannot truthfully stay where you have been, or whether you ever overstayed, you will at the very least have a passport with a dangling stamp.

Comment: @Relaxed I’ve checked now and the Italian long term visa application form doesn’t ask about overstays. So assuming officials wouldn’t place a ban, getting a fresh passport should ‘reset’ their status without breaking any laws.

Comment: @shoover whether she's been in Europe for slightly more than 600 days or slightly more than 700 days is not particularly important to this question.

Comment: @JonathanReez Would changing a passport not be picked up via biometrics (which *are* in the system, AFAIK)? And/or possibly the recording of what seems likely to be a pretty large fine? Dutch and Denmark procedures are described here, as further examples of which countries would impose a ban https://www.mynta.nl/en/knowledge-base/overstay-and-entry-ban-how-does-it-work

Comment: @Traveller Which system? Presently biometrics are not taken for persons who do not require a visa.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Working on the presumption that the person had a Schengen student visa, altho whether that is actually the case is unclear from the question.

Comment: @Traveller If that was the case then when the visa/residence permit ended must be stated in the question. The day after is then when the 90 days starts (if the visa was longer than 3 months). Only then could the possible overstay be calculated. In its present form the question really cannot be answered. Voting to close.

Comment: @deceze Yet that's exactly how it works for some legacy bilateral agreements (where you are allowed an additional 90 days in one country even after spending 90 days elsewhere in the Schengen area) and other corner cases. Meanwhile, third-country residents in one Schengen country are also theoretically limited in the time they may spend visiting other countries in the area but that's not enforced either. Clearly, this friend's understanding of the rules was deficient and a bit self-serving but these rules can be complex and legality and burden of proof / enforcement are distinct issues.

Comment: @phoog I realize that it's not relevant to _this_ question. That was more of a general PSA.

Comment: I seriously doubt that this can be solved and avoid an entry ban. The penalties for overstaying are indeed different from country to country, but e.g. Denmark will impose a 5 year entry ban already for overstaying more than 30 days and here, we are talking about a year and a half. I would not be surprised if such an overstay is an obvious entry ban candidate in all Schengen states.

Answer (score 2):

I would say your best bet is to leave via an airport where US citizens [can use the Biometric/eGates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_border_control_system#European_Union_and_Schengen_Area). This minimizes the odds of scrutiny by border officials. Make sure you buy a direct flight from said airport to the US, in case you do end up facing trouble, as this would minimize the odds of being delayed. Currently such eGates are available in:

- Belgium
- Finland
- France
- Italy
- Netherlands

Another option is to exit on foot via the Spain/Gibraltar border. As outlined in [How does Schengen know I didn't overstay if exiting through Gibraltar by air?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/72228/how-does-schengen-know-i-didnt-overstay-if-exiting-through-gibraltar-by-air), the exit checks conducted by Spanish authorities at that location are often lax, especially on the weekends. Even if a stringent exit check is conducted, there's a chance that the border guards will be lenient to your friend and avoid imposing an entry ban, as there's generally more forgiveness towards citizens of countries that don't require a visa to enter the Schengen area. Make sure you're extremely polite to the border authorities and apologize for staying so long. Make sure you have a ticket out of Gibraltar to the US before crossing the border, in case the UK border officials notice your overstay. Having a ticket and stating that you're only passing in transit should alleviate their concerns.

Good luck and please don't overstay in the future - the consequences can be extremely unpleasant and the extra days are never worth the legal hassles.

Comment: Is there a risk that Gibraltar Immigration officials notice / have a problem with what appears to be a very lengthy overstay? US citizens [don’t need a visa](http://www.gibraltarborder.gi/visa) to enter Gibraltar as a tourist of course, but a difficult conversation or even an entry refusal might be on the cards if they do notice. Plus the OP’s friend needs to figure out how they will get off Gibraltar - it seems like the UK might be the only [flight destination](https://www.gibraltarairport.gi/content/documentation-requirements) which again might cause a problem on arrival in the UK.

Comment: @Traveller having a ticket out of Gibraltar to the US (via the UK) should alleviate any immigration concerns

Comment: I don’t disagree. However the linked answer is 7+ years old, so Brexit and recent heightened security concerns across Europe might mean the Spanish and Gibraltarian authorities are a bit more alert and thorough than they used to be.

Comment: @Traveller sure, which is why I don't think this is guaranteed to work. But OP needs to exit *somewhere* and I think this is the best option.

Comment: I would worry that anything else than a direct Schengen -> US flight carries with it a risk of being detained. In this situation, if she doesn't get admitted into Gibraltar, I'd assume that the Spanish border guard would have to detain her, transport her to some airport with flights to the US, etc, for an overall extra unpleasant experience.

Comment: @Arno you're right, updated with a better alternative

Comment: In the Netherlands at least the screen in the eGate will direct third-country citizens to approach a border guard to get a stamp. I don't know if there is a sign on the gate that would allow them to catch someone pretending to be an EU citizen to skip that part of the process but if that's the case, you definitely would have drawn attention.

Comment: Incidentally, US citizens can also use eGates (Parafe) in France.

Comment: @Relaxed I was a bit confused by the wiki article - do these gates not require pre registering your fingerprint?

Comment: @JonathanReez The article uses the past tense when describing this. The French-language article and official website (service-public.fr) only discuss facial recognition and do not mention this (historical) requirement at all. I also think I have used PARAFE gates recently with a US citizen who hadn't registered anything but I may mix things up with Schiphol where I have definitely done that as well. I don't remember how stamping works in France.

Comment: I may be mis-remembering but I think in Sorrento, Italy recently, the ‘non EU’ departure e-gate was segregated so that after using it I could not reach the boarding gate without passing a Border official waiting to stamp my passport.

Comment: At CDG at least, US passports get directed into Parafe gates (when the Parafe gates are open, which is inconsistent) where the passport is manually stamped, though I don't know how much scrutiny the passport will necessarily get.